# how to get single latest record from a view and test it in console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I kinda have 2 questions. I have following model and method to get the latest record from view. but when i try to test in console i get error `undefined method or variable vCustomerDetails` why i am getting the error?

Also, how do i select only one column from view?

```
SELECT TOP 1 HasConditionFlag FROM vCustomerDetails
WHERE vCustomerDetails.UserID = @user_id
ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
```

Model

```
module Customer
  class CustomerUsage < ActiveRecord::Base

self.table_name = 'vCustomerDetails'

def self.has_condition_flag(user_id)
  vCustomerDetails
    .where("vCustomerDetails.UserID = #{user_id}")
    .order('vCustomerDetails.EntryDate DESC')
    .last
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe `@table_name` inside of `self.has_condition_flag` will help you

Comment: tried it. same error

Comment: See, `vCustomerDetails` is a local value to `has_condition_flag`. You can't address to it. That is what the error about

Answer (score 0):

Remove  vCustomerDetails

```
module Customer
  class CustomerUsage < ActiveRecord::Base

self.table_name = 'vCustomerDetails'

def self.has_condition_flag(user_id)      
    where("vCustomerDetails.UserID = #{user_id}")
    .order('vCustomerDetails.EntryDate DESC')
    .last
   end
  end
end
```

to select a limited number of columns use

```
.select('HasConditionFlag')
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked

```
 def self.has_condition_flag(user_id)
      CustomerUsage
        .select("vCustomerDetails.HasConditionFlag")
        .where("vCustomerDetails.UserID = #{user_id}")
        .order('vCustomerDetails.EntryDate DESC')
        .first
```